# C# MySQL Problems

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

The following code is throwing an error: `ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {        
    public String conString =
      "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" +
      "SERVER=localhost;" +
      "DATABASE=habcms;" +
      "USER=root;" +
      "PASSWORD=password;";

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                
      OdbcConnection db = new OdbcConnection();
      String quer = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'Joshwaa'";
      OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(quer, db);
      OdbcDataReader dString = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      string theValue = dString.GetString(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In english? Haha. I'm new to c#

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `.Open()` the connection.

Comment: I'm now getting `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`

Comment: I've done that. I added `db.Open();` below `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(quer, db);`

Comment: Yes, but since I'm new to C# I have no idea what it means.

Comment: You need to set the `ConnectionString property`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have `OdbcConnection db = new OdbcConnection(conString);` and `public String conString=`(conString does have a connection string inside it, too long to c+p

Comment: `OdbcConnection` has a `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: Got that to work, now it's returning saying there's no data exists for the row/column. Argh!

Comment: You need to call `Read()` to move to the first row.  Read the documentation for `DataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

You must open the connection using Open():

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OdbcConnection db = new OdbcConnection();
        String quer = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'Joshwaa'";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(quer, db);
        db.Open();
        OdbcDataReader dString = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string theValue = dString.GetString(1);
}
```